# Google Compute Engine fails to reboot with error Unrecognized mount option "NOFAIL_OPTION" or missing value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gce-persistent-disk

I have two disks attached to instance. one of them is presistent disk that was created along with instance (20GB). Another one created and attached later(pd-balanced). I have created a swapfile in the second disk as I wanted more space(not sure if this could be a problem).

Everything worked for a month before I restarted server. I also had fstab entry for mounting the second device.

Lost complete access after reboot and could only see above logs from serial console access from browser.

```
Found device PersistentDisk. 
Starting File System Check on /dev/…be8-b463-45c0-ad15-ce57fbf70a8d... 
Started File System Check Daemon to report status. Found device PersistentDisk UEFI. 
Mounting /boot/efi... 
Mounted /boot/efi. Started File System Check on /dev/d…63be8-b463-45c0-ad15-ce57fbf70a8d. 
Mounting /mnt/disks/rajtek... 
EXT4-fs (sdb): Unrecognized mount option "NOFAIL_OPTION" or missing value Failed to mount /mnt/disks/rajtek. See 'systemctl status mnt-disks-rajtek.mount' for details. 
Dependency failed for /mnt/disks/rajtek/swapfile.
```

Need help in restoring access and disks. Please suggest.

Comment: Found device PersistentDisk.
         Starting File System Check on /dev/…be8-b463-45c0-ad15-ce57fbf70a8d...
 Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
 Found device PersistentDisk UEFI.
         Mounting /boot/efi...
 Mounted /boot/efi.
 Started File System Check on /dev/d…63be8-b463-45c0-ad15-ce57fbf70a8d.
         Mounting /mnt/disks/rajtek...
EXT4-fs (sdb): Unrecognized mount option "NOFAIL_OPTION" or missing value
 Failed to mount /mnt/disks/rajtek.
See 'systemctl status mnt-disks-rajtek.mount' for details.
 Dependency failed for /mnt/disks/rajtek/swapfile.

Comment: 1) Move your comment to your question. 2) Include `/etc/mnttab` in your question. 3) I strongly advise not to use swap in cloud VMs.

Comment: Is that all you're getting from serial console output ? Maybe you could login using [serial console interaction](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/connect-to-serial-port) ?